# SQL Developer query. Which PO has the most ship_to? How many? What is the most popular ship_to?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Which customer PO has the most ship_to? How many ship_tos?  What is the most popular ship_to?

So far I have:

```
select cust_po_number, count(ship_to_org_id) 
from order_lines_all 
where
```

I am unsure what the next steps are or how to find the most, amount, and most popular. The table order_lines_all has tons of information about orders that come in daily. I need to find out how many orders are being shipped to a certain place... Which orders have the most shipped and what ship to address is the most popular for receiving the orders. Thank you for the help!

By address or place I mean ship_to_org_id

Comment: It is probably worth confirming your table structure, and explaining what you are trying to do in reasonable detail so people can help you.

Comment: I added more details to hopefully help understand a bit more.

Comment: Still not enough info, please [edit] in your table structure and some sample data